# How can i Create a 2nd list to store the value of each roll as it occurred? Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a python dice game I want it to record each value of the roll 
for example the dice rolled a 6,3,2,4,5,1,6,4,4,3,2,4 until the limit(reach) reaches 50 below is my code:

```
    import random
    throws = 0
    sixes = 0
    fives = 0
    fours = 0
    threes = 0
    twos = 0
    ones = 0
    reach = 50
    total = 0
    question = input ("Play Yes/No")
    if question == "Yes":
        question = True
    else:
        question = False
    while total < reach and question:
         roll = random.randint(1,6)
         throws +=1
         total += roll
         if roll == 6:
            sixes +=1
         elif roll == 5:
            fives +=1
         elif roll == 4:
            fours +=1
         elif roll == 3:
            threes +=1
         elif roll == 2:
            twos +=1
         elif roll == 1:
            ones +=1
         else :
            print("Try again later")
    if question :
        print("Total throws : ",throws)
        print("Total : ",total)
        print("Total 6's : ",sixes)
        print("Total 5's : ",fives)
        print("Total 4's : ",fours)
        print("Total 3's : ",threes)
        print("Total 2's : ",twos)
        print("Total 1's : ",ones)
    else :
        print("Your Loss!")
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the problem? it seems very straightforward to me: create a list and add something every time the while loop happens again (after every roll)

Comment: Also, you could try using a list to store how many ones, twos, ... you had instead of a different variable for each one. It could make your program much shorter and prettier

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, how can I create a 2nd list to store the value of each roll as it occurred, you start with an empty array (`order = []`), then after each roll you append the roll to the end of the array (`order.append(roll)`).

A couple other things could be improved with your code as well.

- Since dice rolls are being counted, its much easier to tally using an list/array and just incrementing the corresponding index
- If you are keeping track of the rolls by saving the order of the rolls, then you don't need to keep track of the sum, you can just use `sum(order)`
- If you are keeping track of the rolls by saving the order of the rolls, then you don't need to keep track of the total number of rolls, you can just use `len(order)`
- If you are using an array instead of individual variables to keep track of the counts, then you can put the print statement into a for-loop

Here's the improved program:

```
import random
rolls = [0]*6
order = []
limit = 50

question = input ("Play Yes/No")
if question == "Yes":
    question = True
else:
    question = False
while sum(order) < limit and question:
     roll = random.randint(1,6)
     order.append(roll)
     rolls[roll-1] += 1

if question :
    print("Order of rolls: ", order)
    print("Total throws : ",len(order))
    print("Total : ",sum(order))
    for i in range(len(rolls),0,-1):
        print("Total ", i, "'s : ", rolls[i-1])

else :
    print("Your Loss!")
```